# How to make sure capturing group is more than 5 characters?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using this code:

`(?i)(?<!see )(?<!\d)(?<!")(?<!“)ITEM.*?1A.*?\n*(?<!")(?<!“)RISK.*?FACTORS(?<!")\n*([\s\S]*?)\n*ITEM.*?1B`

It is grabbing text that are between `ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS` and `ITEM 1B.`, but how can I only grab the capturing group with more than 5 characters?

Full string:

```
ITEM 1A.    RISK FACTORS

123

ITEM 1B.

ITEM 1A.    RISK FACTORS

In addition to other information in this Form 10-K, the following risk factors should be carefully considered in evaluating us and our business because these factors currently have a significant impact or 

ITEM 1B.
```

So, desired capturing group would be:

```
In addition to other information in this Form 10-K, the following risk factors should be carefully considered in evaluating us and our business because these factors currently have a significant impact or
```

and not:

```
123
```

Comment: try using `{5, }` wherever you require more than 5 characters to be captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting is done close to the data like this.
Can significantly shorten the regex replacing `[^\S\r\n]` with `\h` if needed.
Group 1 contains the trimmed data.

`(?sm)^[^\S\r\n]*ITEM[^\S\r\n]+1A[^\S\r\n]*\.[^\S\r\n]+RISK[^\S\r\n]+FACTORS[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n\s*(\S(?:(?!^[^\S\r\n]*ITEM).){3,}?\S)\s*^[^\S\r\n]*ITEM[^\S\r\n]+1B[^\S\r\n]*\.`

https://regex101.com/r/ChQseo/1

Expanded

```
 (?sm)
 ^ [^\S\r\n]* ITEM [^\S\r\n]+ 1A [^\S\r\n]* \. 
 [^\S\r\n]+ RISK [^\S\r\n]+ FACTORS [^\S\r\n]* \r? \n 

 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      \S 
      (?:
           (?! ^ [^\S\r\n]* ITEM )
           . 
      ){3,}?
      \S 
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s* 

 ^ [^\S\r\n]* ITEM [^\S\r\n]+ 1B [^\S\r\n]* \.
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
(?i)(?<!see )(?<!\d)(?<!")(?<!“)ITEM.*?1A.*?\n*(?<!")(?<!“)RISK.*?FACTORS(?<!")\n*([^\r\n]{5,}?)\s*\n*ITEM.*?1B
```

might be somewhat close to what you have in mind, not sure though.

It is likely to work with `re.DOTALL` flag too:

```
import re

regex = r'(?i)(?<!see )(?<!\d)(?<!")(?<!“)ITEM.*?1A.*?\n*(?<!")(?<!“)RISK.*?FACTORS(?<!")\n*([^\r\n]{5,}?)\s*\n*ITEM.*?1B'
string = '''

ITEM 1A.    RISK FACTORS

123

ITEM 1B.

ITEM 1A.    RISK FACTORS

In addition to other information in this Form 10-K, the following risk factors should be carefully considered in evaluating us and our business because these factors currently have a significant impact or 

ITEM 1B.

'''

print(re.findall(regex, string, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

> ['In addition to other information in this Form 10-K, the following
>   risk factors should be carefully considered in evaluating us and our
>   business because these factors currently have a significant impact
>   or']

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/awKplE/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/awKplE/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---